# Use all Ram on Blender when rendering? (Cycles and Blender Render)

Tags: rendering, performance, memory-management, optimization

I have 32 GB Ram on my computer, how can i make Blender use all (or at least, the most) of the RAM when rendering?

Comment: It should work, although of course it will only use what it needs. The only way to make it use all of it is too have a really complex scene (tons of high-res textures, massive polycount, etc.)

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! But isnt there any option to force the software to use more RAM than needed?

Comment: Eh, what? Using more won't make it any faster, it will just make it so that other applications can't use those resources. Also I don't think it is possible, although you might possibly be able to make it reserve certain amounts of RAM.

Comment: I use RAMdisks to put some software on very fast storage. Not really what you meant, but some sort of forced RAM usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**
Memory is for storing information. If blender doesn't have 32GB of information to store, then it won't use up 32GB of memory.

To *force* blender to use more ram than it needs would mean reserving memory and not putting anything in it (a waste), or filling it with useless data which doesn't help blender render (also a waste).

**TL;DR:** This doesn't really seem like it would be useful.